# Airflow XCom send variables inside templating

Tags: bash, airflow, templating

I've been trying to send a the contents of a variable to Xcom in a bash script. However, I am failing at it.

```
test_bash = """
export test_val='123'
{{ ti.xcom_push(key='1',value=test_val) }}
echo $test_val
"""

bash_tash = BashOperator(
    task_id='test',
    bash_command=test_bash,
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)
```

In the code snipped above. When I try to pull it. I'm not able to send anything to Xcom. I have tried sending text in single quotations and it works fine.

Is there a way to send variables from bash scripts to xcom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it differently using a BashOperator to push your value:

```
test_bash = """
export test_val='123'
echo $test_val
"""

bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='test',
    bash_command=test_bash,
    xcom_push=True
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)
```

[image: task instance > XCom]

And then you pull the value into another task.